# Issue with group by while using case with aggregate functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your advise to add group by for below piece of code. I tried couple of things but it is giving not a group by function error to me.

```
Select rec_id,
Case when is_eff=1 and min(date_dt) > dt1 and min(date_dt) <= (dt1 + 90)
Then 'Yes'
Case when is_eff <> 1 and impl_dt is not null and min(impl_dt) > dt1 and min(impl_dt) <= (dt1+90)
Then 'Yes'
Else 'No'
End as column
From Table
Group by rec_id
```

Error: Not a group by expression

Any suggestions on this please.

Comment: You should show us your attempt so we know a bit more about what you're trying to achieve. I don't see a group by in your example query anywhere, so where are you trying to add it?

If you just want a group by after the "From Table" then check : https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-group-by/

What fields are you trying to group on?

Your question is not complete, check out: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; an explanation of the problem you are trying to solve; and the expected output for your sample data. While you state you have an error (and it is obvious where the error is as you aggregate by some columns but have others that you are not aggregating by), nowhere do you explain what the problem is that you are attempting to solve so we cannot tell you what a "correct" solution would look like.

Comment: You may have added error message but you still have not explained the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am trying group based on record id and trying to check the above conditions along with aggregate functions to set the Yes or No based on outcome of condition. But, something is going wrong with the addition of case with aggregate functions. It is throwing an error like not a group by expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You type CASE WHEN THEN, CASE WHEN THEN,...

Syntax is different than what I found on oracle docs:
https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-case/

Being CASE WHEN THEN, WHEN THEN, WHEN THEN,...

Also, fields you are not using aggregate functions on in your CASE should also be included in your group by clause.

```
Select rec_id,
Case when is_eff=1 and min(date_dt) > dt1 and min(date_dt) <= (dt1 + 90)
Then 'Yes'
when is_eff <> 1 and impl_dt is not null and min(impl_dt) > dt1 and min(impl_dt) <= (dt1+90)
Then 'Yes'
Else 'No'
End as column
From Table
Group by rec_id,dt1,is_eff,impl_dt
```

Comment: Thanks Swedo for your answer and time :-)